# How to Install phpSHIELD loader in live server?

Tags: php, web-hosting

I am using PHPMotion for my video sharing website. After installation of PHPMotion, I got an error message like

"
**PHP script /home/dir/public_html/phpmotion/classes/config.php is protected by phpSHIELD and requires the phpSHIELD loader ixed.5.2.lin. The phpSHIELD loader has not been installed, or is not installed correctly. Please find the required loader within phpSHIELD installation directory or visit the phpSHIELD php encoder site to download it.**
"

Is it possible to install ixed.5.2.lin in a live server ? How can I solve this issue? I've attached the error msg screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: already i tried on that link,there u can get a file named  "ixed.5.2.lin". I got it and I placed in project's root folder but thats not running. then only i asked in stackoverflow. I dont know where to place "ixed.5.2.lin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how i did it on my 64 bit vps, but you can use similar procedure on 32 bit.

Download loaders for Linux 64b and copy ixed.5.3.lin inside the php extensions dir. 
You can find it using the following command:

```
php –i | grep extension_dir
```

Then open /etc/php.ini and add the next line at the end of the file

```
extension="ixed.5.3.lin"
```

Save the changes and restart apache (service httpd restart)

Answer (score 2):

Are you on a vps or dedicated server?

Download the required loader, place it in your php extensions folder, then open php.ini and link to the extension using:
extension="ixed.5.2.lin"
then restart your httpd

If you dont have access to these files then you may have to ask your host to do it for you.

More info can be found here http://linuxwindowsmaster.com/how-to-install-the-phpshield-loaders-on-linux-windows-server/ or here http://wiki.phpmotion.com/PHPShield53